# In Oracle how to extract year from date and convert to number?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract the year from 4 different fields, convert the values to numbers, and then compare those values to another value.  The error I get is "inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE".  Obviously my attempt to change the year to a number is not working.  Where is my error?

```
select  pc.a00_pnum
    ,pc.a06_edition
    ,pu.c26_year_built
    ,TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C38_UPDT_HEAT)) "yr_ht_updtd"
    ,TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C35_UPDT_PLUMB)) "yr_plumb_updtd"
    ,TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C34_UPDT_WIRE)) "yr_wire_updtd"
    ,TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C22_UPDT_ROOF)) "yr_roof_updtd"
    from tfprpt.pcommon pc
    join tfprpt.punit pu
    on pc.a00_pnum = pu.a00_pnum
    and pc.a06_edition = pu.a06_edition
    where pc.a06_edition = (select max(pc2.a06_edition) from tfprpt.pcommon pc2 where pc2.a00_pnum = pc.a00_pnum) and
    pc.a09_xdate >= '11-May-18' and
    pc.d14_status = 'I' and
    (
        pu.c26_year_built > pu.C38_UPDT_HEAT or 
        pu.c26_year_built > pu.C35_UPDT_PLUMB or 
        pu.c26_year_built > pu.C34_UPDT_WIRE or 
        pu.c26_year_built > pu.C22_UPDT_ROOF
    );
```

Comment: If you are using, oracle then simply use the to_char as I specified in answer below.

Comment: What is data type of pu.c26_year_built???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extract()` produces a number, so you can simplify:

```
TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C38_UPDT_HEAT)) "yr_ht_updtd"
```

to:

```
EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C38_UPDT_HEAT) as "yr_ht_updtd"
```

I don't know what data type `pu.c26_year_built`.  If it is a number, then repeat the extract:

```
    pu.c26_year_built > extract(year from pu.C38_UPDT_HEAT) or 
    pu.c26_year_built > extract(year from pu.C35_UPDT_PLUMB) or 
    pu.c26_year_built > extract(year from pu.C34_UPDT_WIRE) or 
    pu.c26_year_built > extract(year from pu.C22_UPDT_ROOF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using extract to change what shows in the select statement is different from what you put in the where clause. You should just need to do the same thing in the where clause.

```
select  pc.a00_pnum
    ,pc.a06_edition
    ,pu.c26_year_built
    ,TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C38_UPDT_HEAT)) "yr_ht_updtd"
    ,TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C35_UPDT_PLUMB)) "yr_plumb_updtd"
    ,TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C34_UPDT_WIRE)) "yr_wire_updtd"
    ,TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C22_UPDT_ROOF)) "yr_roof_updtd"
    from tfprpt.pcommon pc
    join tfprpt.punit pu
    on pc.a00_pnum = pu.a00_pnum
    and pc.a06_edition = pu.a06_edition
    where pc.a06_edition = (select max(pc2.a06_edition) from tfprpt.pcommon pc2 where pc2.a00_pnum = pc.a00_pnum) and
    pc.a09_xdate >= '11-May-18' and
    pc.d14_status = 'I' and
    (
        pu.c26_year_built > TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C38_UPDT_HEAT)) or 
        pu.c26_year_built > TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C35_UPDT_PLUMB)) or 
        pu.c26_year_built > TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C34_UPDT_WIRE)) or 
        pu.c26_year_built > TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(year FROM pu.C22_UPDT_ROOF))
    );
```

Comment: The EXTRACT function could return the string 'UNKNOWN' which of course would cause the call to TO_NUMBER() to fail, so be sure to allow for that.  Always expect the unexpected!  More info:https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639

Comment: EXTRACT returns a NUMBER, there is no need to wrap the return value within TO_NUMBER.